# Using a click command once, and then disabling it

Tags: javascript, html, css, unbind

Here's what I'm trying to do. I have two buttons on prompt 0, yes or no. If you click yes, the box moves to the left, fading out as it does so and Prompt 1 shows up. If you click No, the box moves to the right, prompt 2 shows up. I am using Z-index to tell it which prompt should be on top. Now, when I click yes, it goes to prompt 1 and if I click on the area where the Yes or No buttons were, nothing happens. All is fine here.

When I click on No, it fades out (Doesn't go left, but that is not my primary concern) and goes to prompt 2. BUT when I click on the REGION (the yes Cannot be seen)where the YES was, it goes to prompt 1. I've tried unbinding clicks on both scripts, but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.appIMG1').one('click.appIMG1',function () {
        $(this).unbind('click');
        $("#app1").animate({
            left: '250px',
            opacity:0
        });
        $("#app2").fadeIn('slow');
    });
});


$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".appIMG2").one('click.appIMG2', function() {
        $(this).unbind('click');
        $("#app1").animate({
            right: '250px',
            opacity:0
        });
        $("#app3").fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

Z index for prompt 0 is 10, for prompt 1 is 9, for prompt 2 is 8 respectively.

Comment: Can we get a jsfiddle of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to unbind the click event from everything, not just the item being clicked. Instead of using `$(this).unbind('click')`, you need to unbind it from all clickable elements, like this (this is an example just using the 2nd button, but it'd need to be done for both):

```
$(".appIMG2").one('click.appIMG2', function() {
    $('.appIMG1, .appIMG2').unbind('click');
    $("#app1").animate({
        right: '250px',
        opacity:0
    });
    $("#app3").fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jake. That worked!

I have another question, I'm trying to animate it to go left when I click yes, it animates by moving to the left, and fading. But it's not doing the same if I click No. I want it to move to the RIGHT and fade when i click no, but it doesn't work when I replace the Left with Right in the second script. It just fades out. It works when I use left but not right. What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your CSS is pretty convoluted, so it's hard to decipher. I'd recommend  refactoring most of it. However, if you don't want to do that and just want the box to move to the right and fade out, you should change `right: '250px'` to something like `left: '550px'` or some such number. Again, this isn't a great solution, but it'll work for your specific code. http://jsfiddle.net/jakelauer/4ZQLq/5/